# return the rows representing days that were hotter than average for the zip code

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, average, aggregate-functions

Please take a look at the attached image for the question as well as the corresponding data table and an example of what the output should look like.

[image]

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: When you post a homework question, you should always: (1) show what **you** tried, and where you encountered difficulties; and (2) state the level of learning you are at. For example, specifically for this type of problem, to avoid reading the data twice and an unnecessary join, the SQL Standard introduced and Oracle implemented **analytic functions**. But if you didn't learn about them in class, I doubt that the instructor will want you to use them in your homework (proving beyond any doubt that you didn't do it yourself). So - you need to state the level of your class.

Comment: @mathguy, I appreciate the comments and yes I am in agreement with you. If you take a look at my previous questions I have always submitted an example of what I had come up with prior to asking anyone for assistance. The output that you see in the screenshot was actually derived by me. However the issue is that I did not use SQL to come up with that answer and needed a refresher. I had an Idea of what the query would look like however I was hoping not to confuse anyone by posting what I had come up with and get straight to the point. Either way, your comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @ace123 - OK, thank you for clarifying. It is still not clear though, even after your response, whether analytic functions are "in scope" for you.

Comment: @mathguy, yes, Analytic functions are "In scope" for me. I cant say that I've used them a lot in SQL since my current SQL knowledge is at a Basic level, however I find myself using these analytic functions mostly in Excel (which is how I was able to derive the output based on the provided data in the question) and in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using `nested SQL` with `AVG` group function and `left outer join` :

```
select z2.zip_code, z2.measurement_date, z2.noon_temp
  from zip_temps z2 left outer join
   (
   select avg(z1.noon_temp) noon_temp, z1.zip_code
     from zip_temps z1
    group by z1.zip_code  ) z3
    on (z2.zip_code=z3.zip_code)
   where z3.noon_temp < z2.noon_temp;
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3a54/3)

Comment: The average of the temps is 12,16666.... (sound like the screenshot is wrong too...) and your query include the one who have 12 too.
    SELECT * FROM zip_temps
    WHERE noon_temp > (SELECT AVG(noon_temp) FROM zip_temps)

[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3a54/6)

Comment: @Stv Notice OP tells us that "hotter than average for the `zip code`". Average is `13,3333...` for the zip code 22043, `11` for the zip code 22046

Comment: ha yes sorry for the mistake, didn't read carefully that was asked by zipcode, forgive me.

Comment: @Stv not problem friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using analytic functions.

```
select zip_code, measurement_date, noon_temp
from   (
         select zip_code, measurement_date, noon_temp,
                avg(noon_temp) over (partition by zip_code) as avg_temp
       )
where  noon_temp > avg_temp
;
```

(Add an `order by` clause at the end if needed.)

The older approach is to have an aggregate subquery, to process the entire input table once and produce the average temperature for each zip code. Then the main query reads the main table a second time, it joins to this aggregate subquery by zip code, and outputs the needed rows. So the base table is read twice, and we have a join as well. (Other approaches, such as correlated subqueries, would require even more work, but the optimizer is smart enough to transform them into a join.)

Analytic functions were introduced specifically for this kind of problems, to reduce the amount of work needed. The average temperature (by zip code) is calculated essentially the same way (by partitioning or grouping by zip code), it is attached to every row in the input, and then the `where` clause in the outer query compares two values in the same row output by the subquery. There is no need to read the base data a second time, and there is no join.

Comment: Based on your comments, am I correct in assuming that your query would first group the zip code and then take the average "Temp" based on the zip code? If so then I don't believe this would work in this scenario since the ask here is to write a query that would spit out above average temp data grouped by zip codes. For instance, average temp for zip code 22046 is 11 and 22043 is 13. However, when averaging out all of the temperature data provided we have an average temp of 12. Thus the output will greatly vary based on the approach/order of operation.

Comment: @ace123 - What I understood from your original post is the following: take a zip code, and the different dates for that zip code. Compute the average temperature (for that zip code only). Then return - in the output - the dates, for that same zip code, where the temperature is greater than the average (also for that zip code). Rows in the input table that have a DIFFERENT zip code do not affect this computation. In your example, rows with zip 22046 are compared to the average temp of 11. Rows with zip 22043 are compared to the average temp 13.33333. Isn't that what you needed?

Comment: To see what the subquery produces (and then to understand what the main query does), you may run just the subquery, by itself, and examine its output. That will help you see what the analytic function does - the main feature is that it attaches a "copy" of the average value to every input row for the same zip code. This is why you don't need to read the base table a second time, and you don't need a join. Each row will have both its own temperature and the average temperature FOR THE SAME ZIP CODE, but averaged over the different dates.